# Hadoop lookup store options

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

We are planning to migrate our existing application into hadoop. We are currently using many lookup tables/files for reference.

what should be the best option to store such tables/files in hadoop ecosystem

1) Create hive/hbase lookup tables
      will it require separate mr job just to join this lookup file?

2) HDFS file used a reference lookup

Also should we take this decision on size of the lookup tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the best option depends on many factors like the size and nature of the data, network infrastructure..etc. You may consider the following options:

- Copy the data to the distributed cache so that the nodes can load it
  into a hashmap
- Use a key/value store within the mappers/reducers. Eg: [Redis, HBase or Voldemort](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1470521).
  Note that DB access may cause **huge** performance hit.
- Store the lookup data on the HDFS and when needed join it to the dataset you are    processing. [Pig](http://pig.apache.org/), a higher level abstraction over Hadoop can be used here.

If you are going to use a key-value store, I'd recommend looking into [Voldemort](http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/) which is actually a distributed hashtabe.
You may populate its store via a simple Hadoop job ([read-only store](http://data.linkedin.com/blog/2009/06/building-voldemort-read-only-stores-with-hadoop) feature).

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the data is small then [Distributed Cache](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#auxdata) can be used. The lookup data will be copied all the required nodes for execution.

While using a database to store the lookup values, consider the number of the connections the mappers/reducers will make to the database.